# replacing even rows with columns

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a SNPSfile which I was using to create covariance matrix in Bayenv, so each column in this file corresponds populations and rows are SNPs, but for every SNP I have 2 rows (for two alleles), look like below (2 * nsnps "rows" and npops "columns"):

```
7      2     2     0      6      2     2
1      0     0     0      0      0     0
0      2     2     0      0      0     0
1      0     0     0      0      0     0
```

So in this example above I have 7 populations (columns) and 2 SNPs (rows). I need to modify the format of this file a bit. In the new file each row should correspond to one SNP and the number of columns should be twice the number of populations because each pair of numbers corresponds to each allele. So the new file should look like this ( nsnps "rows" and 2*npops "columns"):

```
7   1   2    0    2   0    0   0    6   0   2   0   2   0
0   1   2    0    2   0    0   0    0   0   0   0   0   0
```

is there any way that I could do this manipulation in R? I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Is that a data frame?

Comment: yes, it is a data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
x <- split(mydf, rep(1:(nrow(mydf)/2),each=2))

t(sapply(x, function(x) matrix(as.matrix(x))))
```

gives:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
1    7    1    2    0    2    0    0    0    6     0     2     0     2     0
2    0    1    2    0    2    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
```

You can also do:

```
x <- split(mydf, rep(1:(nrow(mydf)/2),each=2))
newdf <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(x, function(x) matrix(as.matrix(x), nrow = 1)))
```

and get a dataframe back:

```
> newdf
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14
1  7  1  2  0  2  0  0  0  6   0   2   0   2   0
2  0  1  2  0  2  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
> class(newdf)
[1] "data.frame"
```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(V1 = c(7L, 1L, 0L, 1L), V2 = c(2L, 0L, 2L, 0L), V3 = c(2L, 0L, 2L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(6L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V7 = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L)),
                  .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Many thanks Jaap, that is exactly what I want. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you basically want to subset the data, getting only the even numbered rows, you can do the following. Assuming the data is stored in a matrix `m`. Here, I select the rows by generating a sequence of number which represent the row indices to index the matrix using the `seq()` function. This will work for data.frames as well.

```
> m <- matrix(c(1:33), nrow = 11, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) 
> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    4    5    6
 [3,]    7    8    9
 [4,]   10   11   12
 [5,]   13   14   15
 [6,]   16   17   18
 [7,]   19   20   21
 [8,]   22   23   24
 [9,]   25   26   27
[10,]   28   29   30
[11,]   31   32   33
> m[seq(from=2, to=nrow(m), by=2),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]   10   11   12
[3,]   16   17   18
[4,]   22   23   24
[5,]   28   29   30
```